# Get minimum value in an array of floats till it's exhausted in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, loops

Suppose I have an array `a=[1.8 1.2 2.2 1.6]`. I want to write a code so that I can get the smallest value till the values in the array are exhausted.

The desired output at the first step:

`1.2`

This value is then assigned to `int_SOC` and acts as an input for a while loop below:

```
fin_SOC = 3.2
i=0
    while True:
        if int_SOC < fin_SOC:
            int_SOC += output_params.iloc[i, 3]
        else:
            break
        
        i+=1
        print(int_SOC)
```

Only at the end of this while loop `int_SOC` should get the next smallest value that is in our case `1.6`.

Here, `output_params` is a pandas time-series data frame.

As the next step, we are left with an array `a=[1.8 2.2 1.6]`. Now the desired output: `1.6` which is again assigned to `int_SOC` and `while` loop is again executed.

And so on...

Comment: What is wrong with your code? And what is meant by `exhausted`?

Comment: how about `min(a)` ?

Comment: @PCM by 'exhausted' I meant till each value is being used.

Comment: @balderman It gives only the smallest value. I want to have values in ascending order. :)

Comment: So sort the list.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first step of getting the values, smallest first can be achieved by just sorting the list:

```py
a = [1.8, 1.2, 2.2, 1.6]
for item in sorted(a):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
1.2
1.6
1.8
2.2
```

Comment: What if I want to assign these sorted values to variables say `m`, `n`, `o`, `p` ?
ie `m=1.2`, `n=1.6`, `o=1.8`,`p=2.2`

Comment: use: `dict(zip(list('mnop'), sorted(a)))`

Comment: @Nikhil: No, don't do that.

Comment: @quamrana Any particular reason?

Comment: @Nikhil: Yes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) question has lots of answers.

Comment: @quamrana: I am totally confused by reading these answers. I want to do it because each value has to go through a set of `if-else` conditions in the next steps. Also, the size of the array above is dynamic as the values are user input. Could you please suggest me a way out?

Comment: Yes, convert your code snippet into a function and then you'll be able to call it with each element of `sorted(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the values one after the other in order is called sorting ;)

Just use a builtin method for that:

```
a=[1.8, 1.2, 2.2, 1.6]
for value in sorted(a):
    print(value)
```

output:

```
1.2
1.6
1.8
2.2
```

Comment: Hell ya! I was so much into the next steps of my code I forgot the basics :D
Thank you